# Write a shortcut for long psql SELECT

Tags: postgresql, psql

How to alias a complex select to just print the result to console with a simple command?

During debugging I need to execute the same select many times. The query is very long, with a dozen of columns and few joins, what is the simplest way to create a shortcut for that? Using history is the best option so far, but also has some drawbacks.

I tried to use `\set` but it can only work for a very simple expression like this:

```
# \set four SELECT (2+2);
# :four

 ?column? 
----------
        4
(1 row)
```

I also tried to write a function, but I do not know how to print the result of the SELECT or return it properly.

Comment: Create a view and select from the view.

Comment: 0) put it into a different session and use command repetition. 1) put it into a file and include the file. 2) put it into a function and select the function. 3) put it into a prepared statement and execute the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  @Gordon Linoff, I found a very simple solution:

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS
    SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g 
        FROM bigtable
        LEFT JOIN bigtable ON bigtable.a=othertable.a
        LEFT JOIN bigtable ON bigtable.b=othertable2.b
        LEFT JOIN bigtable ON bigtable.c=othertable3.c
        ORDER BY a DESC 
        LIMIT 10;
```

Then just type at any time:

```
table foo;
```